# Como passar o data com o id para a controller sem permitir que o usuário faça manipulação pela tela?

Tags: c#, ajax, razor

Botão:

```
<a id="btnExcluir" type="button" class="btn btn-icon-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="@UtilResources.VIEW_TEXTO_EXCLUIR_REGISTRO" onclick="ExcluirProduto( @item.ProdutoId )"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
```

Função ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ExcluirProduto(ProdutoId) {

        var result = confirm('@UtilResources.VIEW_MENSAGEM_CONFIRMACAO_EXCLUSAO');

        if (result) {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Delete", "Produto")";
            var data = { id: ProdutoId };

            var LoadOptions = {
                validatorElement: "produto_validation_server_validation",
                type: "post",
                blockUI: false,
            };

            AjaxCall(url, data, LoadOptions);
        }
    };

</script>
```

Controller:

```
 [CotacaoContratoSecure(Tela = new[] { enuDominioTela.Produtos }, Acao = new[] { enuDominioTelaAcao.Excluir })]
        public ActionResult Delete(ProdutoDeleteViewModel produtoDeleteViewModel)
        {
            ProdutoDeleteDTO produtoDeleteDTO = new ProdutoDeleteDTO(produtoDeleteViewModel.UserCredentials)
            {
                Id = produtoDeleteViewModel.ProdutoId,
                SegmentoId = produtoDeleteViewModel.SegmentoId.HasValue ? produtoDeleteViewModel.SegmentoId.Value : 0
            };

            ProdutoService.Excluir(produtoDeleteDTO);

            return JsonResultHelper.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", obterListaGrid()));
        }
```

Comment: *"sem premitir que o usuario faça manipulação pela tela"* se o usuário for esperto ele pode editar e não tem muito o que fazer do lado dele, trate isso do lado server, na controller